# Prestashop - hookDisplayOrderConfirmation return "Unexpected Protected" error

Tags: php, oop, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have created a new Prestashop module (PS ver 1.5.4), and in the module, there is a hook,

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params)
{
    /* Place your code here. */
    echo "hello world"; die();
}
```

However, when I tried to run it, it always returns an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in /presta/root/folder/install/modules/folder/controllers/front/payment.php on line 71
```

Line 71:

```
protected function _assignSummaryInformations()
{
......
```

Which is belong to the following class:

```
class SomeModulePaymentModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
......
```

I assume that the module that I have created doesn't go along with the existing module. But am stuck with it, I definitely can't change anything on the existing module.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: are you sure that there is no syntax errors? php -l file.php . What happens when you chnage protected on private or public?

Comment: It is definitely a syntax error

Comment: @SergiiP Before i create this new module, everything works just fine with the other module (that is now "conflicting" with my module). I am checking now for syntax error now...